# Are JPA entity relationships reciprocated?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've always wondered if JPA entity relationships are reciprocate or not. Let's take `@OneToOne` Java 7 tutorial says: "**One-to-one: Each entity instance is related to a single instance of another entity**" [Java 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm#BNBQA).

Does this mean that each instance of the other entity is related with one instance of this entity? Not clear for me.

But Microsoft in [Types of table relationships](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190651%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) say : "**In a one-to-one relationship, a row in table A can have no more than one matching row in table B, and vice versa. A one-to-one relationship is created if both of the related columns are primary keys or have unique constraints.**" Very clear, but does this apply to JPA(standard)/Hibernate(impl)? Or is is that each company assigns the meaning that they want to the relationships?

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String parent;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ChildEntity childEntity;
```

And the child entity (NOTE: Unidirectional relationship):

```
@Entity
public class ChildEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String child;
```

And a test which passes, note that both parent entities are related to **the same** child:

```
    @Test
public void canCreateAndRetrieve() throws NotSupportedException, SystemException, DaoException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException {
    //given        
    ParentEntity pe1 = new ParentEntity();
    pe1.setParent("Parent1");

    ParentEntity pe2 = new ParentEntity();
    pe2.setParent("parent2");

    ChildEntity childEntity1 = new ChildEntity();
    childEntity1.setChild("Child1");

    pe1.setChildEntity(childEntity1);
    pe2.setChildEntity(childEntity1);

    utx.begin();
    try {
        //when
        parentDao.create(pe1);
        parentDao.create(pe2);
    } finally {
        utx.commit();
    }
    utx.begin();
    try {
        List<ParentEntity> results = parentDao.getAll();
        //then
        Assert.assertEquals(2, results.size());
        ParentEntity dbParentEntity1 = results.get(0);
        ParentEntity dbParentEntity2 = results.get(1);

        assertEquals(dbParentEntity1.getChildEntity().getChild(), dbParentEntity2.getChildEntity().getChild());
    } finally {
        utx.rollback();
    }
}
```

If I modify the childEntity to make the `@OneToOne` bidirectional, the test fails:

```
@Entity
public class ChildEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String child;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "childEntity")
private ParentEntity parentEntity;
```

Does this mean that in Hibernate relationships are not reciprocate unless they are bidirectional? And that Hibernate allows you to have some sort of hybrid/partial relationships => the unidirectional relationships? Do you guys have some documentations I could read?

Comment: "reciprocate" doesnt make any sense - you actually meant "bidirectional" and : yes, JPA relationships are unidirectional by default, you can map anything to anything without defining the other side of the relationship, this  enables developers to create quite a few flexible data models - its a very useful feature. If you specifiy both sides of the relationship it implicitly becomes a bidirectional one with automatic synchronization or even cascade _(if you specify the cascade-option)_.

Comment: Yes, OneToOne means that A has 0 or 1 B, and that B has 0 or 1 A. Otherwise, it would be a ManyToOne.

Comment: @specializt English is not my mother tongue, changed 'reciprocate' to 'reciprocated', obviously I meant the adjective not the verb, my bad sorry. What I mean by reciprocated is the "vice versa" from Microsoft's definition above. I don't mean the bidirectional in terms of "navigational access" if this is what you mean, you got me wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet Can two different As, point to the same B in a one to one relationship? I thought it can't, but then again, my test passes.

Comment: If you had unique constraint on foreign key column from `A` to `B`, as the Microsoft quote says, your test would fail. So, the two quotes you mention basically say the same thing.

Comment: So a OneToOne is not correct unless I have the unique set to true? Are there many kinds of OneToOne, so far we discovered 2, when you put the unique to true, and when you don't?

Comment: You could say that, IMHO. Without it, there would be no difference between `OneToOne` and `ManyToOne` in the database.

Comment: @PredragMaric Thanks a lot. It was not clear for me. So if you don't put unique, then the relation is not "reciprocated", ok I think I understand, and that makes sense, I was confused because at uni they told us, that these relations are reciprocated, and now we see they can, or can not be.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far to say there are many (or two) different kinds of  `OneToOne`. The database should reflect your model, if something is logically intended to be `OneToOne` then it should also be implemented like that in the database (with unique constraint), weather it is unidirectional or bidirectional. Because, it is not uncommon to encounter a requirement in the middle of the project to expose the other side of the relation, to convert from uni to bidirectional. That is where you will fail if you don't treat it as it logically is from the start.